# Calling JavaScript function from PagedListPager doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, pagedlist

I have a `Html PagedList` like below,

```
<div id="contentPager">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ServerPaging", new { page }))
</div>
```

And this is the output HTML for pager,

```
<div id="contentPager">
     <div class="pagination-container">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="active">
                 <a>1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#targetContainer" href="/MyController/ServerPaging?page=2">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#targetContainer" href="/MyController/ServerPaging?page=3">3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want the click event Javascript function to be called when I click page numbers from this pager without going to server action `ServerPaging`.
This is how I have implemented the Javascript event listener.

```
$(document).on("click", "#contentPager a", function () {
            //............
        });
```

But it's still calling the server action `ServerPaging`.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML rendered by this `PagedListPager` that you're attaching click handlers to?  Can you provide a [mcve] of just the client-side code where you're trying to prevent another action from taking place?  Are you simply missing a `preventDefault()` and/or `stopPropagation()` somewhere?

Comment: Where are you calling/executing this function?

Comment: @Tushar, javascript is in the same page with the pager code.

Comment: @David, I already updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Url from the `href` property and set to void function.

```
    <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" 
data-ajax-update="#targetContainer" href="javascript:void(0)" data-pageno="2" >2</a>
```

Then you need to get the page number from the `data-pageno` attribute in the event function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#contentPager a", function () {
    var pNo = this.data("pageno");
    alert(pNo);
});
```

Comment: The html result is just runtime output of Html.PagedListPager , cannot change like this.